# If the electric field is not a gradient, can it exist?

Tags: electricity, vector-fields

We know that the gradient of the electric potential function $V(x,y,z)$ is the electric field. But not all vector fields are gradients, for example $y\hat{i}-x\hat{j}$ is not a gradient. Does this mean that an electric field given by $\vec{E}=y\hat{i}-x\hat{j}$ cannot exist? In particular does this mean there is no arrangement of charges which could create such a field? What is the correct interpretation here?

Note: the example I have given here is a bit stupid, because the field is two dimensional and this is probably impossible anyways. But there are of course three dimensional fields which are not gradients, I just can't think of one at the moment. If someone can please let me know.

---

Edit: to answer the comment below I will show that $y\hat{i}-x\hat{j}$ is indeed not a gradient. If it is, then there exists a function
$f$ such that
$∇f(x, y) = yi − xj$.
Obviously
$\frac{∂f}{∂x}(x, y) = y$,
$\frac{∂f}{∂y}(x, y) = −x$ so
$\frac{∂^2f}{∂y∂x}(x, y) = 1$,
$\frac{∂f}{∂x∂y} (x, y) = −1$
and thus $\frac{∂^2f}{∂y∂x}(x, y) \neq \frac{∂f}{∂x∂y} (x, y)$.

This contradicts the mixed partial derivative theorem: the four partial derivatives
under consideration are everywhere continuous and thus, according to the mixed partial
derivative theorem, we must have

$\frac{∂^2f}{∂y∂x}(x, y) = \frac{∂f}{∂x∂y}(x,y)$.

Comment: why isn't yi−xj a gradient?

Comment: yes you are right.I deleted my answer.

Comment: I would suggest looking at Maxwell's equations.  The electric field can also be produced by a time varying vector potential which can give you that kind of field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *electrostatics*, there is always the *scalar potential* (voltage) such that $\vec\nabla\phi = -\vec E$.

This does not hold true in general electromagnetism, which is described by the [electromagnetic four potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential) $A$ consisting of the electrostatic potential $\phi$ and the magnetic vector potential $\vec A$ such that
$$ \vec E = -\vec\nabla\phi - \partial_t \vec A$$
$$ \vec B = \vec\nabla\times\vec A$$

So, not being a gradient is *not* sufficient to conclude that a given vector field cannot be the electric field, since for non-zero $\vec A$, i.e. in the presence of currents/moving charges/magnetic fields, we do not expect $\vec E$ to be the gradient of a scalar field.

An electric field would be impossible if it cannot arise as the solution to [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), but as long as your magnetic field is unconstrained, you can obviously just set $\partial_t \vec B$ and $\rho$ such that the given field fulfills them, so you cannot from the form of $\vec E$ alone judge whether it is physically permissible.

Comment: How exactly does this answer my question?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou: I expanded the answer to more clearly address your question.

Comment: Ok now I understand. So a couple questions: (1) so you are saying in an electrostatic situation, the field I described is impossible. (2) Is there an "easy" example of a field which is not a solution to Maxwell's equations (something non-pathological if possible). (3) I am trying to think of a charge distribution which would produce a two-dimensional field (all the field vectors lie in the same plane). Is there an "easy" example?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou: 1. Yes, exactly. 2. Well, your field together with $\vec B = 0$ is impossible. As I say, there is no $\vec E$, however pathological, that cannot be created by choosing $\rho$ and $\vec B$ appropriately. 3. Infinitely big charged sheet, perhaps?

Comment: for #2 I am asking is there a field $\vec{E}$ for which for which there is no choice of $\vec{B}$ that gives no solution to Maxwell's equation. In other words a field which cannot exist in any situation, not just in an electrostatic situation.

Comment: @Joshua: Since $\vec\nabla\times\vec E = -\partial_t B$, you would have to choose $\vec E$ such that the time-integral of the LHS gives a $\vec B$ that cannot fulfill Maxwell's equations. I'm not 100% certain, but it *could* happen that $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$ fails. (By looking at the hypothetical electric field that a moving magnetic monopole would produce, for example)